# Prove that if $x\geq y - \epsilon$ for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$, then $x \geq y$

Tags: real-analysis

This technique was used in a measure theory proof in my probability course, and I don't recognize it, though it seems like it'd be something basic from analysis. Thanks! (For anyone curious, it was a proof that for a measurable function $X\geq 0$ and any sequence of simple functions $Y_n$ increasing to $X$, $\int Y_n d\mu\to\int X d\mu$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Suppose otherwise. That is, suppose that $x<y$. If you take $\varepsilon\in(0,y-x)$, then …